# Bash parameter substitution strip first # character

Tags: bash, substitution

Is there any easy way of stripping/replacing the first occurrence of the `#` character from a bash variable with parameter substitution?
I tried the following but it did not work:

```
$ VERSION=0.11.3-issue#18.6a0b43d.123
$ echo ${VERSION#'#'}
$ echo ${VERSION#\#}
```

I want my output to be:

```
0.11.3-issue18.6a0b43d.123
#           ^
#           no #
```

Any easy solution for this? Perhaps in a completely different way?

Comment: I just want to remove/replace the # character

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to 'delete' the first occurrence of the #, use `${parameter/pattern}`.

```
${parameter/pattern/string}
       Pattern substitution.  The pattern is expanded to produce a pat-
       tern just as in pathname expansion.  Parameter is  expanded  and
       the  longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with
       string.  If pattern begins with /, all matches  of  pattern  are
       replaced   with  string.   Normally  only  the  first  match  is
       replaced.  If pattern begins with #, it must match at the begin-
       ning of the expanded value of parameter.
```

- The match is done using pathname expansion (think `?` and `*`).
- Additionally `#` at the beginning of the pattern has a special meaning, which is why we replace it with `\`. And the sequence `\#` then matches a literal `#` without the special meaning of `#` at the beginning of the pattern.

**Example**

```
VERSION=0.11.3-issue#18.6a0b43d.123
echo ${VERSION/\#/}
```

**Output**

```
0.11.3-issue18.6a0b43d.123
```